Mesh cutoff convergence in SIESTA
By increasing mesh cutoff, the total energy of system is becoming less negativei i.e, increasing.

My Siesta File settings for monolayer ZnO are as:
SystemName ZnO221.cif
SystemLabel ZnO221.cif

NumberOfAtoms 8
NumberOfSpecies 2

%block Chemical_Species_label
1 30 Zn
2 8 O
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeParameters
 6.54  6.54  20.000000  90.000000  90.000000 120.000000 
%endblock LatticeParameters


AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
1.6187 0.9345 2.6141 1
-0.0000 3.7382 2.6141 1
4.8560 0.9345 2.6141 1
3.2373 3.7382 2.6141 1
0.0000 1.8691 1.9829 2
-1.6187 4.6727 1.9829 2
3.2374 1.8691 1.9829 2
1.6187 4.6727 1.9829 2
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

%block PAO.Basis # Define Basis set
Zn 2 # Species label, number of l-shells
n=4 0 2 P 1 # n, l, Nzeta, Polarization, NzetaPol
0.0 0.0
n=3 2 2 # n, l, Nzeta
0.0 0.0
O 3
n=2 0 2 E 40 -0.9
5.5 2.4772420
n=2 1 2 E 40 -0.9
6.02252744236 2.3079428
n=2 2 1 E 40 -0.9 Q 7.6631318 .0724687
6.02252744236
%endblock PAO.Basis


XC.functional       GGA
XC.authors          PBE
SolutionMethod  diagon
MeshCutoff        $i Ry
DM.MixingWeight   0.02
DM.Require.Energy.Convergence   T
DM.Energy.Tolerance     1.e-6 eV
SCF.DM.Tolerance  1.d-5
SCF.H.Tolerance   1.d-4 eV



%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
1   0   0   0.0
0   1   0   0.0
0   0   1   0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack


This isn't surprising.
One should not expect energies to always get smaller as convergence parameters changes.
In this case, the smaller cutoffs are simply simulating a wrong minimum given the boundary conditions you impose.
As always, all parameters should be converged. And here it is quite important also with k-points.
